# Error in calculating Combined Standard deviation in R using dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

i have the following data of non overlappping population, which i have summarized to check mean, median, sd, counts etc as mentioned in column below

```
structure(list(ProductionBatcBatchNo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Batch18200616", "Batch18200702", 
"Batch18200703", "Batch18200704", "Batch18200705", "Batch18200708", "Batch18200709", 
"Batch18200710", "Batch18200711", "Batch20200712", "Batch20200715", "Batch21200701", 
"Batch21200703", "Batch21200704", "Batch21200705", "Batch21200706", "Batch21200708", 
"Batch21200709", "Batch22200630", "Batch22200701", "Batch22200702", "Batch22200707", 
"Batch23200620", "Batch23200701", "Batch23200702", "Batch23200703", "Batch23200704", 
"Batch23200706", "Batch24200717", "Batch25200707", "Batch54200711", "Batch55200705", 
"Batch55200706", "Batch55200707", "Batch56200701", "Batch56200702", "Batch56200704", 
"Batch56200705", "Batch56200709", "Batch56200710", "Batch57200701", "Batch57200702", 
"Batch57200703", "Batch57200704", "Batch57200706", "Batch57200708", "Batch57200709", 
"Batch57200710", "Batch57200711", "Batch57200712", "Batch57200714", "Batch57200717", 
"Batch58200701", "Batch58200702", "Batch58200703", "Batch58200704", "Batch58200705", 
"Batch58200708", "Batch58200710", "Batch58200712", "Batch58200713", "Batch59200622", 
"Batch59200701", "Batch59200702", "Batch59200704", "Batch59200705", "Batch59200706", 
"Batch59200707", "Batch59200708", "Batch59200709", "Batch60200618", "Batch60200702", 
"Batch60200705", "Batch60200708"), class = "factor"), gCapSetParametero_Kep = c(690, 
700, 710, 680, 700, 680, 680, 680, 690, 670), MeanActParameter = c(685.04, 
698.01, 696.86, 665.23, 603.48, 685.15, 677.98, 687.18, 616.37, 
666.29), MedianActParameter = c(683, 698, 691, 665, 698, 686, 679, 
689, 691, 667), MaxActParameter = c(726, 726, 726, 672, 738, 701, 
705, 720, 720, 694), MinActParameter = c(672, 676, 675, 658, 0, 515, 
657, 278, 175, 643), SDActParameter = c(10.57, 10.54, 16.26, 2.61, 
217.61, 9.87, 10.66, 18.21, 182.13, 11.27), Counts = c(1152L, 
2338L, 212L, 214L, 157L, 482L, 2722L, 5738L, 628L, 783L), OverallSD = c(12.47, 
12.47, 12.47, 144.58, 144.58, 9.87, 10.66, 63.34, 63.34, 11.53
), RSD1 = c(1.8, 1.8, 1.8, 22.62, 22.62, 1.44, 1.57, 9.31, 9.31, 
1.73), OverallCounts = c(3702L, 3702L, 3702L, 371L, 371L, 482L, 
2722L, 6366L, 6366L, 851L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

then for calculating a single Combined Standard deviation for each batch i was trying to make use of the following formula

```
combinevar <- 
  function (xbar = NULL, s_squared = NULL, n = NULL) 
  {
    if (length(xbar) != length(s_squared) | length(xbar) != length(n) | 
        length(s_squared) != length(n)) 
      stop("Vector lengths are different.")
    sum_of_squares <- sum((n - 1) * s_squared + n * xbar^2)
    grand_mean <- sum(n * xbar)/sum(n)
    combined_var <- (sum_of_squares - sum(n) * grand_mean^2)/(sum(n) - 
                                                                1)
    return(c(grand_mean, combined_var))
  }
```

And then Performing the following code for calculating Combined Standard deviation using above function

```
Output6 = Output4%>%
          group_by(ProductionBatchNo)%>%
          summarize(CombinedSD= combinevar(xbar=MeanActParameter, s_squared = Output4$SDActParameter, n= Counts))
```

But i am getting this error, dont know why. its working with other formulas

```
Error: Problem witBatch `summarise()` input `CombinedSD`.
x Input `CombinedSD` must be a vector, not a function.
i Input `CombinedSD` is `combinevar(...)`.
i TBatche error occurred in group 1: ProductionBatcBatchNo = "Batch18200616".
```

Comment: It looks like you are mixing programming approaches which can get quite confusing. You might want to do the work of `combinevar` using `summarize` to rewrite variables. `Output4 %>% group_by(batch) %>% summarize(SS=sum(SS), mean=sum(n*mean)/n())`. Also, heads up, there is a math error when you write `sum_of_squares <- sum((n - 1) * s_squared + n * xbar^2)`

Comment: oh is it so, Actually all i want to do is find the a single value of standard deviation who is influenced by the no. of counts. Not able to do so till now

Comment: If you dataframe has columns for sum `s`, sum of squares `ss` and `n` you can use `group_by` and `summarize(s=sum(s), SS=sum(SS), n=sum(n))` and then the usual `df$sd <- (df$SS-(df$s)^2)/df$n`.